# How to compare rows of a matrix in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I was wondering how to compare the row elements of a matrix. I want to do that to verify if all of the row elements are multiple of themselves. I already know that a numer is multiple of another number if their `mod == 0`.

But, lets suppose that I have this matrix

[image: matrix]

So i want to compare the first row with the numbers 4 and 8, so all the elements are multiple of themselves because 4 is multiple of 8 and so is the other row with 5 and 10.

Could you please help me? Thank you?

Comment: `I want to do that to verify if all of the row elements are multiple of themselves` - A number is always a multiple of itself. `4 is multiple of 8` - No, at least not in the common interpretation as `8 divides 4`. Please elaborate on what you want.

Comment: What are you wanting if one is not a multiple? Does everything stop when the first one fails the condition? Do you continue and get the rows of all the failures?

Comment: `var checkMultiple = arr => arr.every(a => {
  return a.every(v => !(v%a[0])); 
});` Using `array#every` you can check if first value divide all the other number in your matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the matrix is in nested arrays. You could do 2 loops through and store the first number to modulo.

Eg
This will only display on your console showing which row does not follow your rule

```
var arr = [[4, 8], [5, 11]]

for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++) {
        var compare = arr[i][0]
        // compare here
        if (arr[i][j] % compare == 0){
            // console.log(true)
        } else {
            console.log("Matrix row #" + i + " is not divisible by first number")
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: This will not only display the row that causes the failure but it will show all failures in that row. Meaning if you have row lengths of 30 and 29 fail on just `arr[0]` then you will get 29 `"Matrix row #0 is not...."`. You can simply `console.log` your error row message and assign j to `arr[i].length + 1` to break out of the row.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is a true/false then you can do something like @rsutti suggested:

```js
var arr = [[4, 8, 11, 16], [5, 10, 15, 20]];

function checkArr(a){
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        var indexZero = a[i][0];
        for (var j = 1; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            var min = Math.min(indexZero, a[i][j]);
            var max = Math.max(indexZero, a[i][j]);
   
            if (max % min !== 0){
                return false;        
            } 
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}

console.log(checkArr(arr));
```

Simply do a double loop, using the head for modulo. You will have to find the min and max. The function returns false at the first instance of failing the condition. Of course you may want to modify this later as you haven't stated what you want upon failure(s).